# collect and using percentage for setting thresholds on filesytems

Tags: threshold, collectd

I currently have collectd 5.4 installed on my linux host and attempting to use percent to trigger a notification when the threshold has been exceeded but it doesn't appear to work. The threshold for CPU does work however. My current config:

```
  LoadPlugin threshold
     <Plugin threshold>
         <Plugin "cpu">
           <Type "cpu">
           Instance "idle"
           DataSource "value"
           WarningMin 10
           FailureMin 5
           Hits 25
           Persist true
           </Type>
      </Plugin>
      <Plugin "df">
        Instance "usr"
          <Type "df">
          Instance "free"
          WarningMin 50
          FailureMin 55
          Percentage true
          Persist true
          </Type>
       </Plugin>
```

Anyone ever gotten this to work?

Answer (score 0):

`Percentage` inside `threshold` blocks only works for values with multiple datasources, which is not the case for the `df` plugin for collectd 5.x.
Fortunately since 5.4 there is the `ValuesPercentage` option for the `df` plugin which will let you achieve your goal using the `percent_bytes` type.

Here's a full example config that will poll filesystem usage and emit notifications to syslog when there is no free space on any filesystem:

```
<Plugin syslog>
  LogLevel notice
  NotifyLevel OKAY
</Plugin>

LoadPlugin df
<Plugin df>
  ValuesPercentage true
</Plugin>

LoadPlugin "threshold"
<Plugin "threshold">
 <Plugin df>
  <Type "percent_bytes">
    Instance free
    WarningMin 10
    FailureMin 1
  </Type>
 </Plugin>
</Plugin>
```

Comment: Could you provide an example, using my example on how to configure this? I've tried many variations but none or working.